# Pandas groupby/value_counts for no values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data set that shows count of loads for each category. Given below is the data I have.

```
Name,Count1,Count2,PercentDiff,Category
Store A,10,4,0.4,Less than 1%
Store B,20,26,1.3,Less than 5%
Store C,12,48,4,Less than 5%
Store D,30,180,6,Less than 10%
```

I would like to get the count for each of the below categories

```
1. Less than 0
2. Less than 1%
3. Less than 5%
4. Less than 10%
5. More than 10%
```

I have used the below rule to categorise each of these entries:

```
new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0, 'Category'] = 'Less than 0%'
new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] == 0, 'Category'] = 'Exact match'
new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0.01, 'Category'] = 'Less than 1%'
new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0.05, 'Category'] = 'Less than 5%'
new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0.1, 'Category'] = 'Less than 10%'
new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] == 0, 'Category'] = 'Exact match'
new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] > 0.1, 'Category'] = 'Greater than 10%'
new['PercentDiff1'] = new['PercentDiff'].astype(int)

Output1 = new.groupby(['Category']).agg(lambda x: x.mad())
Output1 = Output1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
SumMail = pd.value_counts(Output1['Category'].values)
```

However, if the data set has no values for any of the categories I get an error stating no values found for a particular category.

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

KeyError: 'More than 10%'

Could anyone help me modify this code so that it returns 0 for categories that have no records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for pd.cut ?

Comment: Hi Wen, I have never used cut function, will that help return 0 or Nan for categories that do not have values.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your 'Category' column astype categorical dtype:

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].astype('category')
df['Category'] = df['Category'].cat.set_categories(['Less than 0',
                                                    'Less than 1%',
                                                    'Less than 5%',
                                                    'Less than 10%',
                                                    'More than 10%'],
                                                    ordered=True)

df['Category'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Output:

```
Less than 0      0
Less than 1%     1
Less than 5%     2
Less than 10%    1
More than 10%    0
Name: Category, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your dataframe is empty before you do your labeling.

```
if new['PercentDiff'].empty:
    return 0
else:
    new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0, 'Category'] = 'Less than 0%'
    new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] == 0, 'Category'] = 'Exact match'
    new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0.01, 'Category'] = 'Less than 1%'
    new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0.05, 'Category'] = 'Less than 5%'
    new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] < 0.1, 'Category'] = 'Less than 10%'
    new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] == 0, 'Category'] = 'Exact match'
    new.loc[new['PercentDiff'] > 0.1, 'Category'] = 'Greater than 10%'
    new['PercentDiff1'] = new['PercentDiff'].astype(int)

    Output1 = new.groupby(['Category']).agg(lambda x: x.mad())
    Output1 = Output1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
    SumMail = pd.value_counts(Output1['Category'].values)
```

Comment: Hi Tyler thanks for the response. Would it be possible to add a elif statement to the above condition to see if null, if yes return 0 else check for the condition.

Comment: Not sure if that is what you wanted, but returns 0 if that column is null, else does labeling.